# situations in which we say 'sort out with'

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I've come across the article in which the collocation 'sort out with' is used.

The source: http://newyorkcorkreport.com/blog/2014/10/17/the-spirits-of-volunteerism/

> Is this an issue that should be left to the vineyards and wineries to sort out with the labor boards, or is this something that individual supporters of those wineries should be taking up with their legislators?

In this regard, I have a question about this phrase, i.e. in which situations we can say 'to sort out with'. As far as I understand, if we have a dispute with someone over some issues, we want **to sort these issues out with** this person or, say, a regulating body. When we cause somebody any difficulties, we endeavor **to sort these difficulties out with** these people. Does it sound idiomatic when I use the words difficulties, issues, problems together with 'sort out'.

Can we use the preposition 'with' in relation to an inanimate noun?

> I have to sort this problem out with the fraud involving my credit card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contexts like these *with* has two unrelated uses.

- We use a *with* phrase after verbs like *talk*, *discuss*, *argue*, *talk over*, *take up*, *sort out* to designate the other **people** involved in the activity: the people we are addressing. The *with* phrase modifies the predicate—the verb and its complements—and ordinarily comes after the predicate is 'finished',

  > ...an issue ... to sort out ***with*** the labor boards
  >   ...an issue ... to take up ***with*** their legislators
  >   ...a problem ... to discuss ***with*** my boss
- We also use a *with* phrase with nouns like *problem*, *issue*, *difficulty* to designate the **location** of the problem: where the problem arises. The *with* phrase modifies the noun and ordinarily comes immediately after it.

  > a problem ***with*** fraud ...
  >   a difficulty ***with*** English idiom ...
  >   an issue ***with*** his attitude ...

Both of these uses are idiomatic. But (as I suspect you have realized) a problem may arise when your utterance involves **both** a noun **and** a verb which may **each** take a *with* phrase. There are two sorts of problem here:

- The first is ambiguity:

  > We need to discuss this problem with the labour board.

  Is the labour board the source of your problem or the agency you want to discuss it with?

  In conversation the ambiguity will usually not arise: the context and the situation will make it clear to your hearer which you mean, and any misunderstanding will eventually emerge in the conversation and can be explained. But in writing you have to deal with the fundamental rule that “Anything which *can* be misunderstood *will* be”; since you have no opportunity to clear up any misunderstanding you must take particular care to say exactly what you mean.

  I’ll address some rewriting strategies shortly; but one that jumps forward in your example can be addressed here. With some ‘phrasal verbs’—*sort out* is one of them—the second element is *separable*—it can be placed either before or after the Direct Object. However, it should **not** be placed after a ‘heavy’ (many-word) DO, and it should **not** interrupt a DO.  In your example the *with* phrase modifies *this problem* and should not be separated from it. Putting *out* **after** *this problem* leads the reader to believe that *this problem* is the entire DO, so the *with* phrase must be a modifier on the predicate: the person with whom you will *sort out* the problem. That is obviously absurd in this context, so there’s no real harm done; but *out* really should come **before** *this problem*:

  > I have to sort out this problem with the fraud involving my credit card.

  That ‘ties’ the *with* phrase to the problem and makes misunderstanding much less likely.
- The second problem is *horror aequi*: our strong dislike for using the same construction twice in a row with different significance:

  > We need to discuss this problem with the labour board with our lawyers.

  Here there’s no permanent ambiguity, even in writing: when readers get to the end of the sentence they will apply the ‘rule’ that the first *with* phrase modifies the NP *labour board* which immediately precedes it, so the second *with* phrase modifies the predicate-as-a-whole.

  But the sentence is likely cause a brief ‘glitch’ in interpretation—after all, it is not unreasonable for readers to suppose, when they encounter *with the labour board*, that you feel a need to discuss your problem with the people who are causing it. And then you add a second *with* phrase with a different meaning, and that makes readers re-calibrate their interpretation of what the *with* signals—that’s probably why we dislike these doublings. So by the end of the sentence your readers may feel a vague sense that you have made your sentence unnecessarily difficult to follow.

  In conversation this is not a severe problem: you have all the resources of intonation and phrasing to make your meaning clear, and can speak your sentence something like this:

  > We need to discuss this  problem-with-the-labour-board   with our lawyers.

  But you can’t do that in writing.<sup>†</sup> You really need to rewrite. You have a lot of options. For instance, very old-fashioned writers will flip the Direct Object and its modifying *with* phrase to the end:

  > We need to discuss with our lawyers this problem with the labour board.

  There’s enough separation between the *with* phrases here to overcome *horror aequi*. But the separation between the verb and its Direct Object is unnatural and ‘literary’; in modern prose this should be avoided. Another approach would be to separate the two *with* phrases through an ‘information packaging’ strategy like passivization or extraposition:

  > This problem with the labour board needs to be discussed with our lawyers.
  >   This problem with the labour board, we need to discuss it with our lawyers.

  An even better solution is provided in TRomano’s answer: recast one of the *with* phrases.

  > We need to discuss this labour board problem with our lawyers.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Well, you *can*—I just *did*—but that’s going to make your page look very odd, and will be even more annoying than *horror aequi*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> I have to sort this problem out with the fraud involving my credit
>   card.

That is not quite idiomatic.

When used with the collocation "sort a problem out" the prepositional phrase governed by *with* typically refers either to the thing that is having the problem or the entity with whom one is going to sort the problem out.

**When the prepositional phrase refers to the thing having the problem, "with" means "involving", so when you use "involving" as well as "with", it's pleonastic.**

The preposition "with" here expects an object-phrase like this:

> with the water-heater
>
> with my credit card
>
> with the manufacturer
>
> with the store that sold me the widget.
>
> with the police
>
> with my in-laws
>
> with my partners

These are all idiomatic:

**I have to sort this problem out with my credit card.

I have to sort out this problem with my credit card.

I have to sort out this fraud problem with my credit card.

I have to sort out this credit card fraud with the bank.

I have to sort out with the bank a problem with my credit card involving fraudulent use.**

Comment: +0.9 But I can't go along with your characterization of *involving* as 'pleonastic': the problem is with fraud and the fraud involves the credit card, rather than, say, a peculating teller. It is however unnecessarily verbose; recasting the whole as *credit card fraud* is clearly much better.

Comment: I wouldn't argue too strenuously to support my position, but to my mind the sentence (involving a collocation 'to sort out a problem with ...') is pleonastic in several ways (rather than simply wordy). When it hits the word "fraud": "I must sort this problem out with the fraud involving my credit card".  The word *fraud* should have appeared in the slot occupied by "problem* and then the with-clause would specify the interlocutor:  *I must sort  this fraud out with the bank."  Since "problem" occupies that slot, the expectation is that the with-clause will identify the problem realm...

Comment: ...(i.e. with my credit card) or the interlocutor (with the bank). That is, the with-clause won't offer a synonym for "problem".

Comment: Yeah, the problem (*our* problem) is that the problem could be with any of those: the fraud, the credit card, or the bank. You can only *sort it out with* the bank, so that's where you want to leave *with* ... unless (this just occurred to me) you were going to sort out **using** your third-party credit card, e.g. to pay off the bank; and as long as we're being far-fetched, perhaps you would yourself be using your card fraudulently! But your *credit-card fraud* disambiguates nicely.